# how to approach persisting MongoDB documents and subdocuments

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am a bit confused about the way to approach persisting the following classes in mongo.
I have an abstract class BookmarkEntities which has 5 other classes extending from it.

```
public abstract class BookmarkEntity
```

and for example, `public class Folder extends BookmarkEntity`

I would like my Folders to be able to have other Folders inside it as well as other domain entities which derive from BookmarkEntities(a tree structure), below is the field inside a Folder, and a Folder has a method which can set the parent;

```
Vector<BookmarkEntity> list = new Vector<>();

    public void setParentFolder(BookmarkEntity parentFolder) {
    this.parentFolder = parentFolder;

    if (parentFolder.getType() == Type.FOLDER) {
        ((Folder) parentFolder).add(this);
    }
}
```

I have tried various ways to do this and each one continues to give stack overflow error, I presume from infinite recursion.

```
`           /* TEST */
            Folder parent = new Folder("Parent");
            Folder sub = new Folder("Sub");
            sub.setParentFolder(parent);

            bmeRepository.save(parent);
```

`

I was wondering if anybody could point me on the right path to saving documents with subdocuments inside each other. And how to approach this.

Comment: May be you would want to read this for modelling tree structures https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

Comment: Thankyou, using @DBref was the solution to this!